# JSON to R data frame: preserve repeated values

Tags: json, r

I have a JSON data source that is a list of objects. Some of the object properties are themselves lists. I want to turn the whole thing into a data frame, **preserving the lists as data frame values**.

Example JSON data:

```
[{
    "id": "A",
    "p1": [1, 2, 3],
    "p2": "foo"
},{
    "id": "B",
    "p1": [4, 5, 6],
    "p2": "bar"
}]
```

Desired data frame:

```
  id  p2      p1
1  A foo 1, 2, 3
2  B bar 4, 5, 6
```

### Failed attempt 1

I have found this nicely straightforward way of parsing my JSON:

```
unlisted_data <- lapply(fromJSON(json_str), function(x){unlist(x)})
data.frame(do.call("rbind", unlisted_data))
```

However, the `unlist`ing process spreads my repeated value across multiple columns:

```
  id p11 p12 p13  p2
1  A   1   2   3 foo
2  B   4   5   6 bar
```

I expected that calling `unlist` with the `recursive = FALSE` option would take care of this, but it doesn't.

### Failed attempt 2

I noticed that I can *almost* do this with the `I` function:

```
> data.frame(I(parsed_json[[1]]))
   parsed_json..1..
id                A
p1          1, 2, 3
p2              foo
```

But the rows and columns are reversed. Transposing the result mangles the repeated data:

```
> t(data.frame(I(parsed_json[[1]])))
                 id  p1        p2   
parsed_json..1.. "A" Numeric,3 "foo"
```

Comment: P.S. Part of the magic in the `unlist` example involves returning something with type `data.frameRowLabels`. Might that have something to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jsonlite` package can handle this just fine:

```
library(jsonlite)
fromJSON(txt)
#  id      p1  p2
#1  A 1, 2, 3 foo
#2  B 4, 5, 6 bar

fromJSON(txt)$p1
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 4 5 6
```

Comment: Holy json libraries, batman! I was using RJSONIO. Obviously inferior!